# Why can't I access my UIView's class property from another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uitableview

I get the following error when I try to access my cellFront object's title property when I'm within the UITableViewCell subclass that I'm using it in:

[image]

Yet I imported CellFront.h, and it has the property:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I'm on Xcode 4.6 and iOS so I needn't synthesize my variables.

Comment: What is cellFront? You should show more of the surrounding code so we can get some context.

Comment: Can you post the method where that error can be found, or at least the parts that tell us how `cellFront` is initialised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You imported everything you need to import, but you have cast or declared `self.cellFront` as a UIView, not as a CellFront. The compiler is right; a UIView has no `title`.

The problem will be solved when you let the compiler know that `self.cellFront` is in fact a CellFront. Remember, it is not looking at what class this thing *really* is; that won't happen until runtime. The compiler knows only what you tell it.